# Unable to change tick label properties in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

No matter what I seem to do, or whichever past questions I seem to look up - I seem unable to change simple properties of tick labels.

This code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero
from matplotlib.transforms import BlendedGenericTransform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

if 1:
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)

    # thicken the axis lines
    ax.axhline(linewidth=1.7, color="k")
    ax.axvline(linewidth=1.7, color="k")

    plt.xticks([-numpy.pi/2, -numpy.pi/4, 0, numpy.pi/4, numpy.pi/2], [r'$-\pi$', r'$-\pi/2$', r'$O$', r'$\pi/2$', r'$\pi$'], rotation=30)
    plt.yticks([])
    #ax.set_xticklabels([r'$-\pi$', r'$-\pi/2$', r'$0$', r'$\pi/2$', r'$\pi$'], rotation=40, ha='left')

    # end-of-axis arrows
    ax.text(0, 1.05, r'$y$', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transData, ax.transAxes), ha='center')
    ax.text(1.03, 0, r'$x$', transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transAxes, ax.transData), va='center')

    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.xlim(-numpy.pi/2, numpy.pi/2)
    x_width = (abs(plt.xlim()[0]) + abs(plt.xlim()[1])) / 2
    y_width = (abs(plt.ylim()[0]) + abs(plt.ylim()[1])) / 2

    # end-of-axis arrows
    plt.arrow(plt.xlim()[1], -0.003, x_width*0.01, 0,
              width=x_width*0.0015, color="k", clip_on=False,
              head_width=y_width*0.24/7, head_length=x_width*0.024)
    plt.arrow(0.003, plt.ylim()[1], 0, y_width*0.01,
              width=y_width*0.0015, color="k", clip_on=False,
              head_width=x_width*0.24/7, head_length=y_width*0.024)

    for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

    for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

    x = numpy.linspace(-numpy.pi/2, numpy.pi/2, 2500)

    yy = numpy.tan(2*(x - numpy.pi/2))
    threshold = 1000
    yy[yy > threshold] = numpy.inf
    yy[yy < -threshold] = numpy.inf

    ax.plot(x, yy, linewidth=1.2, color="black")
    ax.axvline(x=-3*numpy.pi/4, linewidth=1.0, color="k", linestyle="--")
    ax.axvline(x=-numpy.pi/4, linewidth=1.0, color="k", linestyle="--")
    ax.axvline(x=numpy.pi/4, linewidth=1.0, color="k", linestyle="--")
    ax.axvline(x=3*numpy.pi/4, linewidth=1.0, color="k", linestyle="--")

    plt.savefig('MC6.png')
```

with particular note of this line:

```
        plt.xticks([-numpy.pi/2, -numpy.pi/4, 0, numpy.pi/4, numpy.pi/2], [r'$-\pi$', r'$-\pi/2$', r'$O$', r'$\pi/2$', r'$\pi$'], rotation=30)
```

does **not** rotate the labels by 30 degrees. Likewise if I do other workarounds to change the font-size, the labels always stay the same.

Am I missing something super simple about matplotlib???

Answer (score 4):

Add this line:

```
ax.axis["xzero"].major_ticklabels.set_rotation(30)
```

For the reference, here's a mailing list item where this comes from: http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/rotating-x-tick-labels-bold-labels-with-axislines-toolkit-td7661.html

As to *why* what you do has no effect, I can only guess. A wild guess would be that the state machine (which works under the hood when you call functions from the pyplot namespace) assumes that `plt.xticks` relate to the bottom spine, which you've explicitly set to be invisible.

Comment: Ok that is awesome - now is there a way to change things like horizontal alignment for individual labels?

Comment: I suppose there is, don't know it off the top of my head. I'd start by doing `dir(ax.axis["xzero"].major_ticklabels)` and see if there's anything helpful. Failing that, you can always set the positions of the labels manually, just like you did.